# Does creating a Twilio Capability Token require a request to Twilio's servers?

Tags: twilio

Does creating a Twilio Capability Token require a request to Twilio's servers?

If I understand correctly, creating a Twilio Capability Token involves some kind of encryption process that happens exclusively on my own server. When I call the library to create one, it is not making a call to Twilio's servers, correct?

If it is purely an encryption process, is it an encryption process that's designed to be "slow". If so, how slow?

Comment: Hi Chris, could you please explain what do you mean by slow?

Comment: Hey Louis, some hashing algorithms, such as bcrypt are designed to consume significant amounts of computing time in order to make a brute-force attack more difficult. I assume this might also be done with encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that the creation of the token according to the C# Api, all happens on your own server. The process creates a Json Web Token and that is what is returned from the GenerateToken call. I cannot see anything that would cause the above call to be slow at all.

I know from my server side code, that this process is actually blindingly fast, in our production servers, when a token expires for a Twilio client, it requests a new one from the server and then initialises itself again, this process takes less than 2 seconds to complete and the client is once again able to either make or receive calls, depending on the allowed capabilities.

Perhaps if you share more about what you are experiencing as slow, one would be able to help more?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Louis, thanks for your response! To answer your question: right now, I am not experiencing anything that is especially slow. The reason I am inquiring about the speed is because I am considering putting the token creation in a part of an application that is moderately time-critical.